# how to fill a 2d array with chars of 2 string

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, multidimensional-array

my main purpose is to create something like that

[image]

and here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class EditDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int N = 0;
        int M = 0;
        // char [][] opt = new char [N+1][M+1];

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("gene57.txt");
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
            while (input.hasNext()) {
                String num = input.nextLine();

                String[] parts = num.split(" ");
                String part1 = parts[0];
                N = part1.length();

                String part2 = parts[1];
                M = part2.length();

                System.out.println(part1);
                System.out.println("Number of nucleobase of Sequence 1 is=" + N);

                System.out.println(part2);
                System.out.println("Number of nucleobase of Sequence 2 is=" + M);
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.format("File does not exist\n");
        }
        // x= n+1 , y=m+
    }
}
```

I currently read 2 dna sequence from my txt file and create 2 strings with 2 sequence (M and N) so I have to create a M+1 and N+1 matrix in order to perform my dynamic programming algorithm.

now my problem is this

how can i create this 2d array?
My first dimension should created with chars of my first string (part1) and second dimension with my second string (part2)

How can i accomplish that and later on print it like in the picture.

thank you

Comment: Are you just asking the syntax of creating an (M+1)X(N+1) empty matrix?

Comment: OK, we know what you think you have to do, but we don't know what you have problem with. Question from your title is not enough specific. Please ask more specific question, with example of input and expected output.

Comment: i edited.Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can create an array after the code has started to execute so you have to break the line:

```
char [][] opt = new char [N+1][M+1];
```

In 2 parts, the first goes where it is now just for a declaration:

```
char [][] opt;
```

And the second part goes right after you get the length of M:

```
...
M = part2.length();
opt = new char [N+1][M+1];
```

Cheers